# SQL Substring code to deal with extra characters

Tags: sql, string

I have a string in the format 'Filename_30062021_095700.txt' and I wrote some SQL to get the date bit (in the format DDMMYYYY after the first underscore) then convert to an INT:

```
declare @filename varchar(50), @filename2 varchar(50)

Set @filename = 'Filename_240621_122110.txt'
Set @filename2 = 'Filename_240621_122110_1.txt'

Select CAST(SUBSTRING(@filename, CHARINDEX('_', @filename) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', @filename) - CHARINDEX('_', @filename) - 1) AS Int) As IntDateFilename1
```

The problem I have is where the filename randomly has an _1 character at the end before the file extension.

I can't see what to do to my query that would cope with the extra '_1'. I've written something to check the number of _ underscore characters and if there are three then I could do something differently, I just can't see what to do for the best.

I thought of more or less the same query, except for a Left(@filename, 15) + '.txt' instead of @filename but is there a better solution in case the DD or MM ever appear as one digit?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the 2 surrounding underscores as the markers here:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(filename, CHARINDEX('_', filename) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('_', filename, CHARINDEX('_', filename) + 1) -
              CHARINDEX('_', filename) - 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

A little trick you can do to deal with your `_1` issue in particular is to work with the string *reversed*, then `charindex` gives you the correct character postitions and copes equally well with `_1234` etc

```
Set @filename = 'Filename_240621_122110_1234.txt'
select Reverse(Stuff(Reverse(@filename),(1+CharIndex('.',Reverse(@filename))),( CharIndex('_',Reverse(@filename))-CharIndex('.',Reverse(@filename)) ),''))
```

Comment: I did experiment with reversing the string but didn't get it to work as well as this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just look for `'_'` followed by six digits.  Then remove the initial part of the string and take 6 digits:

```
SELECT LEFT(STUFF(filename, 1, PATINDEX('%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', filename), ''), 6)
FROM t ;
```

Or if you prefer using `SUBSTRING()`:

```
   SUBSTRING(filename, PATINDEX('%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', filename) + 1, 6)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7d3a79074fde56ed7eed9edbf28bcf7) is a db<>fiddle.